# Change an array's value in x86 assembly (embedded in C++)

Tags: c++, assembly, embedded, x86

I am messing around with assembly for the first time, and can't seem to change the index values of an array.  Here's the method I am working on

```
int ascending_sort( char arrayOfLetters[], int arraySize )
 {
   char temp;

__asm
    {

   //???
      }
}
```

And these are what I tried

```
mov temp, 'X'
mov al, temp
mov arrayOfLetters[0], al
```

And this gave me an error C2415: improper operand type

so I tried

```
mov temp, 'X'
mov al, temp
mov BYTE PTR arrayOfLetters[0], al
```

This complied, but it didn't change the array...

Comment: Oddly similar to another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628018/using-an-array-in-embedded-x86-assembly) - is this classwork?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643341/sort-an-array-via-x86-assembly-embedded-in-c-possible

Comment: @Michael Burr: Also oddly, the two question askers have the same avatar. Same IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arrayOfLetters` value is equivalent to a pointer. So, your assembly code might need to be:

```
mov temp, 'X' 
mov al, temp 
mov edx, arrayOfLetters
mov [edx], al
```

In the above code, `edx` is loaded with the address of `arrayOfLetters`. Then the last instruction stores the `al` byte into the address pointed to by `edx`.

Answer (score 3):

When you have a parameter or varaible that is an array, it is actually a pointer to the first element of the array.  You have to deference that pointer in order to change the data that it points to.  For example:

```
__asm
{
mov eax, arrayOfLetter
mov [eax], 0x58
}
```

Or, more generically:

```
__asm
{
mov eax, arrayOfLetter
mov [eax+index], 0x58
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This SO question deals with reading the elements of an array instead of modifying them, but I suspect that the underlying explanation will be largely the same (namely that arrayOfLetters needs to be treated as a pointer):

- [Using an array in embedded x86 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628018/using-an-array-in-embedded-x86-assembly)